# Algebraic closure of a field in constructive mathematics

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ct.category-theory, fields, constructive-mathematics

There is a short note by André Joyal called [Les théorèmes de Chevalley-Tarski et remarque sur l'algèbre constructive](http://www.numdam.org/item/CTGDC_1975__16_3_217_0) (pp. 256-258). It is claimed there that there is a constructive version of the theorem that every fields embeds in an algebraically closed field in the sense that, for every arithmetic universe $\mathcal{O}$ and every field $k$ in it, there is a conservative extension of $\mathcal{O}$ in which the field $k$ embeds in an algebraically closed field.

The note is very short and there are no actual proofs. So, the question is: did this construction appear in the literature in some form?

[I know that if we put some conditions on the field, then the algebraic closure can be constructed in the same universe. I'm not interested in such theorems. I'm looking for a particular construction that was described in the note.]

Comment: I think the idea is to form the theory of an algebraically closed field _containing the original field_ and then take the classifying arithmetic universe. The problem is partly that Joyal hasn't written up his definition of arithmetic universe, so that we are left to try to work with Maietti's definition. Work of Steve Vickers is definitely relevant here too.

Comment: This is worth asking on the categories mailing list,  as Joyal is on there.

Comment: I believe this was the result that motivated the work on dynamical methods. These are connected to forcing extensions. Here is a recent paper on the topic:
A Sheaf Model of the Algebraic Closure
Bassel Mannaa  Thierry Coquand
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.4549

The paper contains a number of historical references.

Comment: Indeed, 
Dynamical method in algebra: effective Nullstellensätze
Michel Coste Henri Lombardi Marie-Françoise Roy
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168007201000264
says Cor 2.8 is similar to Joyal's result.

Comment: References to the works David mentioned:
https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/arithmetic+pretopos